# Difference between chain call of promise and separately?

Tags: javascript, promise, event-loop

Code sample1:

```js
Promise.resolve().then(()=>{console.log('1')}).then(()=>{console.log('2')});    
Promise.resolve().then(()=>{console.log('3')}).then(()=>{console.log('4')});
```

output:

```
1
3
2
4
```

Code smaple2:

```js
Promise.resolve().then(()=>{console.log('1')});
Promise.resolve().then(()=>{console.log('2')}); 
Promise.resolve().then(()=>{console.log('3')});
Promise.resolve().then(()=>{console.log('4')});
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I suppose the first one should has same output as the second. 
Because in sample 1, `then`s have been call in sequence and the callbacks should be arranged one by one. But the result seems the second line `Promise.resolve` cut in line.

Have I misunderstand anything?

Comment: in the first code, `2` isn't invoked until `1` completes, and similarly 4 waits for 3 ... 1 and 3 are on the microtask queue before 2 and 4 are even considered

Comment: Can't understand what you said about wait. Firstly, the promise's state is resolved. nothing need to wait. Secondly, the `then` method self should be called in sync, alghouth inner implement will async handle the passed callback. So there isn't any wait, right?

Comment: no, wrong, a .then is always asynchronous - note the difference between `console.log(Promise.resolve())` and `console.log(Promise.resolve().then(()=>{}))`

Comment: Can u explain the difference, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each callback added through a `.then` will get pushed to the microtask queue when the Promise on which `.then` has been called resolves.
This queue will get executed in FIFO order, and each microtask will get removed from the queue once executed.

Both cases are doing very different things, and to better understand the differences, here is a rewrite of both cases, without any chaining and reordered by execution order, but which is identical to OP's versions in terms of execution.

```js
const cb1 = ()=>{console.log('1')};
const cb2 = ()=>{console.log('2')};
const cb3 = ()=>{console.log('3')};
const cb4 = ()=>{console.log('4')};

// microtask queue []
const p1 = Promise.resolve(); // microtask queue [p1];
const p2 = Promise.resolve(); // microtask queue [p1, p2];

// p1() => add p3
const p3 = p1.then( cb1 ); // microtask queue [p2, p3];

// p2() => add p4
const p4 = p2.then( cb3 ); // microtask queue [p3, p4];

// p3() => cb1 + add p5
const p5 = p3.then( cb2 ); // microtask queue [p4, p5];

// p4() => cb3 + add p6
const p6 = p4.then( cb4 ); // microtask queue [p5, p6];

// p5() => cb2 // microtask queue [p6];
// p6() => cb4 // microtask queue [];
```

```js
const cb1 = ()=>{console.log('1')};
const cb2 = ()=>{console.log('2')};
const cb3 = ()=>{console.log('3')};
const cb4 = ()=>{console.log('4')};

// microtask queue []
const p1 = Promise.resolve(); // microtask queue [p1]
const p2 = Promise.resolve(); // microtask queue [p1, p2]
const p3 = Promise.resolve(); // microtask queue [p1, p2, p3]
const p4 = Promise.resolve(); // microtask queue [p1, p2, p3, p4]

const p5 = p1.then( cb1 ); // microtask queue [p2, p3, p4, p5]
const p6 = p2.then( cb2 ); // microtask queue [p3, p4, p5, p6]
const p7 = p3.then( cb3 ); // microtask queue [p4, p5, p6, p7]
const p8 = p4.then( cb4 ); // microtask queue [p5, p6, p7, p8]

// p5() => cb1 // microtask queue [p6, p7, p8]
// p6() => cb2 // microtask queue [p7, p8]
// p7() => cb3 // microtask queue [p8]
// p8() => cb4 // microtask queue []
```

Comment: I wonder in the first snippet,  after `p1.then()` invoke, seems next is `p3.then()`. why in your demo it's `p2.then()`. I mean the p3, returned by p1, is written first, in chain call format, then there comes with p2 something. Could you explain it?

Comment: I already did, each then adds to the microtask queue. p1 and p2 are added synchronously, before the microtask starts being emptied. So before p1 ever gets executed, global task would have pushed p2.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks very much. You're angel!